# AC power tracks, PCB design guides

Tags: pcb-design, layout

I was wondering about this board Im reviewing. Theres a switching power supply module in this board (red rectangle). 
switching power supply used: https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/220-v-a-3-3-v-5-9-12-15-24-24-2-6-w-3/32853634328.html?
So was added (Conn_WallSocket) not by me, but I was thinking if is correct or follow good PCB practices route 2 phase from AC network on different layers: Neutral on bottom and 220V on top layer? Well, thers 40 mil width track, its for current from AC Network around 10-15A I think so sounds ok. Anyway, if someone see improvements to do on this route let me know. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is the header in the bottom right used for?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a PCB trace width calculator, I think you will find for 10-15A 40mil is a bit undersized. 10A on a 1 inch trace with 1oz/in copper will see a 100C temperature rise.

https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Also depending on what and where this is being used, your distance between high voltage traces to low voltage or isolated signals is defined by regulatory bodies. In the US that is UL, in Europe that is CE.

Layers:

Yes it makes sense to put them on separate payers for better separation.

Comment: still not answer about 2 layers route byt thanks for u comment

Comment: CE and UL are not equivalent.