# Should one pour AC-Neutral copper on bottom layer when routing AC

Tags: ac, mains, copper-pour

I am designing a PCB where there will be AC mains routing/tracks.

What I want to know, is if it is better -for noise reduction- to take one of the AC outputs (Neutral) and pour it on the bottom side of the PCB (On the mains/AC side only of course), as I would do with GND if I was using DC.  (aka using Neutral and Phase routes/traces on different layers as much as possible)

So basically, treat Neutral as GND when considering tracing and copper pouring.

I think this makes sense since the one AC output is the return of the other and vice versa, but I have not seen any recommendations or questions about it while searching/googling, and I think that it might not even make a difference.

The closest to my question is [this issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442479/ac-power-tracks-pcb-design-guides)  But on the answer, @MadHatter says that

> Yes it makes sense to put them on separate payers for better separation.

But I am not happy/satisfied with the "makes sense" reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

1. Neutral could be swapped with the Live Wire due to a number of reasons.
2. Your main goal with AC mains voltage is to keep it as far away from your circuit as possible.

Usually with AC lines, the main concern is that you don't want your system to put noise on the AC lines. You achieve this by using proper input filtering and by keeping the mains lines as short as possible. L and N traces can be on separate layers but don't need to. In any case follow clearence rules between them and from both of them to anything else.

If you still want to shield the AC lines with anything due to whatever reason, then use the Earth conductor for this.